# Registry redirection on 64 bit

Tags: windows, registry, 32bit-64bit

I'm running 64 bit version of Windows 8.1
Times ago I developed a win32 application that creates and access some keys in the windows registry, in a path like:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MY_SOFTWARE
```

Today, in the 64 bit world, I've seen that without doing any changes in the source code, my old 32 bit application creates and access the same keys in a new path:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\MY_SOFTWARE
```

Thanks to a redirection done by the system, with complete transparency from an application point of view.

If I compile my application to be a 64 bit software, will it write under a `"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6464Node\MY_SOFTWARE"` node or back to the standard node `"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MY_SOFTWARE"` ?

Since these keys are accessed by other applications (third party applications both 32 and 64 bit), should I write the keys both in
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\MY_SOFTWARE` and `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MY_SOFTWARE`
 paths so that both 32Bit and 64Bit external applications can see them?

Comment: The 64-bit version, unless you instruct it otherwise, will not write to Wow6432Node.  There is an option you can pass to the registry functions if you want it to (or if you want the 32-bit version not to).  Existing 64-bit third-party applications, if they work now, must already be expecting to find the key in the 32-bit view, so it might not be necessary to put in the 64-bit view as well.

Comment: This is all well explained in the [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5cykbwz4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) about the registry redirector, little point in repeating it here.  Just follow the "see Accessing an Alternate Registry View" link if you need to override the behavior of the redirector, you can't miss KEY_WOW64_32KEY.